# The following error occurred: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command, on Browsestack

Tags: automated-tests, appium, serenity-bdd, browserstack

Script failing on Browserstack (intermittently).

Using serenity-bdd , and executing on browserstack....

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
if (MyDriverClass.deviceType.equalsIgnoreCase("Tablet")) {
capabilities.setCapability("os_version", "8.0");
capabilities.setCapability("device", "Samsung Galaxy Tab S3");
capabilities.setCapability("real_mobile", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.platform",
"ANDROID");
capabilities.setCapability("project", "Tablet_PROJECT");
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.browser", "chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.browser_version", "76.0");
//also used appium version 1.6.5
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.appium_version", "1.7.1");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", orientation);
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.local", browserstackLocal);
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.localIdentifier", 
browserstackLocalIdentifier);
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.debug", true);
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.video", true);
capabilities.setCapability("build", browserStackTCBuild);
return new RemoteWebDriver(
new URL("https://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@hub- 
cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"),`enter code here`
capabilities);
```

I am not sure why getting server side error. Even all the script relate elements and locator is on the page and in view.

Answer (score 0):

The error unknown server-side error is generally encountered when the element you are trying to locate is hidden/ not visible.

You will need to ensure that the element you are trying to locate is in the viewport and nothing is overlaying it. You can read more on the exact causes for the above error [here](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aappium%20An%20unknown%20server-side%20error%20occurred%20while%20processing%20the%20command&type=Code).

Comment: That's not quite right. I already saw this error when Appium client and server version do not match.

Comment: I have read the locator issue which triggers this error, but in my case all the elements are on the page and very much in the viewport. 
@AndiCover , I have mentioned appium version capability as capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.appium_version", "1.7.1"); for browserstack driver instance, but not using any server or external parameters.